# EF Core: override naming conventions

Tags: c#, orm, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am migrating an app to EF Core and I ran into issue with the model definition.

Assume this simple scenario:

```
public class AEntity
{
    public ICollection<BEntity> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class BEntity
{
   public int AId { get; set; }      
}
```

I use the convention *class name*+Entity to distinguish between proper full blown classes and the DB model. But I obviously don't want to use the same naming in the database, I only want to have table names like `A`, `B`, ..

I can simply override this naming convention in `OnModelCreating` using `.Relational().TableName = getRidOfEntity(...)`.

But now, if I want to list the objects of type `AEntity` I get this error:

> 'Invalid column name 'AEntityId'.

Obviously the EF Core creates the foreign key using the original class name and does not look in the overriden model.

How can I rename the foreign key column name in the model? I do not want to use annotations or specify list of types/FKs via fluent API. The model strictly holds some conventions so there are not ambiguities and everything can be set up this way.